# How to use helmet.js from typescript?

Tags: typescript, helmet.js

It is pretty easy to use helmet from pure js per documentation:

```
const express = require('express')
const helmet = require('helmet')

const app = express()

app.use(helmet())
```

But how can I use it from typescript? Typings file exports a bunch of stuff, one of which is helmet interface, which cannot be called as a function.. I can import it like this, but have no idea what to do next, what should I pass to app.use?

```
import * as helmet from 'helmet'
```

I have imported the latest version of both helmet and typings:

```
"@types/helmet": "0.0.43",
"helmet": "^3.18.0"
```

Comment: I'm [in the process of rewriting Helmet in TypeScript](https://github.com/orgs/helmetjs/projects/2). It'll be a little while before I'm done, but keep this in mind if you're looking at this question in a few months or later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its exactly how you can use, just call helmet in the app.use method

```
import * as helmet from "helmet"; // Security

....


    /**
     * Create our app w/ express
     */
    this.app = express();
    this.app.use(helmet());
```

For more details visit this [link](https://gist.github.com/romelgomez/3c1776fab4192c7687883c1a2b972c8c) for a express application with typescript

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Still getting my head around js and typescript, calling interface as a function is an interesting concept.

Comment: Have things changed with helmet v 4.0.0 or @types/helmet v 0.0.47?  I upgraded my helmet version from v 3.23.3 and now I get a compile error "This expression is not callable." for the "helmet()"

Answer (score 16):

**terminal**:

```
npm install helmet
npm install @types/helmet --save-dev
```

**app.ts**:

```
import Helmet from "helmet";

const app = express();
app.use(Helmet());
```

*helmet middleware should be the first thing you activate once you initialized express application object. Also note the titlecase name*

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: helmet_1.default is not a function` helmet@4.1.1 and @types/helmet@0.0.48

Comment: `npm WARN deprecated @types/helmet@4.0.0: This is a stub types definition. helmet provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.`

Answer (score 11):

As of **08.05.2021** with helmet `4.6.0` I am able to do the following in a Typescript project without any types installation:

```
import helmet from 'helmet';
...

app.use(helmet());
```

Just in case for anyone struggling like me.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting in `4.6.1`: TS2769: No overload matches this call.   The last overload gave the following error.     Argument of type '(req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse, next: (err?: unknown) => void) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PathParams'

Comment: @agoldev, could you please provide some context with more details? Maybe something reproducible

Comment: I fixed it. For me it was deleting the `yarn.lock` and re-install using `yarn`. Previous attempts to delete node_modules folder and `yarn` didn't succeed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Happy for you! My pleasure :)

Answer (score 4):

According to [`@types/helmet`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/helmet), the package has been deprecated because helmet now has its own type definitions. So I won't advise you to install the `@types/helmet` package.

To fix the issue, remove the helmet dependency from your `package.json` file, then install the latest version of `helmet` by running:

`npm i helmet`

Answer (score 4):

```
npm install helmet
npm install @types/helmet --save-dev
```

I imported as

```
import * as helmet from 'helmet';
```

and later added it as

```
app.use(helmet.default());
```

`helmet.default()` seemed to do the trick instead of `helmet()`

Comment: This does work. One may refer to this thread for why: https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/issues/343#issuecomment-1006259994

Answer (score 2):

Enable the `esModuleInterop` option in `tsconfig.json` and the warning will disappear.

After that, you don't need to `import * as helmet`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

For helmet version 5.1.0, you need to import it this way:

`import helmet from 'helmet'`

in order to avoid the following warning:

`This expression is not callable.`

Comment: this was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

import helmet this way:

```
import * as helmet from 'helmet';
```

to avoid the following warning:

```
TypeError: helmet_1.default is not a function
```